# Partially initializing base class

Tags: python, inheritance, python-2.6

Couldn't think of a better question title. Feel free to edit. I have a base class which is inherited by many classes (which in turn may have more sub-classes). For each class, I have a sequence of operations I need to perform post-initialization. The sequence is encapsulated in a function `runme()` which performs a series of object method calls

```
class myBase(object): 
    def __init__(self,neg,op,value): 
        self.neg = neg
        self.op = op
        self.value = value
        #Process
        self.runme()

    def runme(self): 
        self.preprocess()
        self.evaluate()
        self.postprocess()

    def preprocess(self): 
        pass

    def evaluate(self): 
        pass

    def postprocess(self): 
        pass
```

The sub-classes have to accept the same attributes as base (and any additional attributes). All of them will over-ride the three functions - `preprocess`, `evaluate` and `postprocess`

```
class childA(myBase): 
    def __init__(self,neg,op,value,ad1): 
        super(childA,self).__init__(neg,op,value)
        self.ad1 = ad1
        #Must call runme() here again??
        runme()

    def evaluate(): 
        #Something using self.ad1
        blah = self.ad1+self.value
```

The way I see it, it creates a problem - `childA` calls the base `__init__` first, which calls `runme()`, which in turn will call `evaluate`. Since child over-rides `evaluate`, the child's definition of `evaluate` is executed, but as `self.ad1` has not *yet* been instantiated, this throws an `AttributeError`

I can remove `self.runme()` from myBase and the problem will probably be gone, but I can further sublcass `childA` into `childAA`

```
class childAA(childA): 
    def __init__(self,neg,op,value,ad1): 
        super(childAA,self).__init__(neg,op,value,ad1)
        self.runme()
```

And the problem can manifest all over again. I can't remove `runme()` from childA's `__init__` because objects of both `childA` and `childAA` can be formed (and will need processing)

Currently, as a workaround, I do not call `runme()` in the `__init__`, instead call it from the calling program after initialization.

```
obja=childA(foo,bar,baz,ad1)
obja.runme()
```

A simpler alternative is to call `super()` at the end of child's `__init__`, but that does not *appear* to be right

Another way is - Tell the base class to defer calling of runme() to the child class. Is this possible? Say in myBase, I do

```
def __init__(self,neg,op,value): 
        self.neg = neg
        self.op = op
        self.value = value
        #Process
        if some_condition which checks if this is being called by a derived class:
            self.runme()
```

Which if these is the best way to solve it? Alternatively, is this a common problem and what are other suggested solutions?

**EDIT**

Two answers were posted (and deleted) which concurred the best way seems to be to leave `runme()` call in the base-class and then call the `super()` at the *end* of child's `__init__`

```
class myBase(object): 
    def __init__(self,neg,op,value): 
        self.neg = neg
        self.op = op
        self.value = value
        #Process
        self.runme()

class childA(myBase): 
        def __init__(self,neg,op,value,ad1): 
            self.ad1 = ad1
            super(childA,self).__init__(neg,op,value)
```

In the case where you need values that depend on existing values,

```
class childA(myBase): 
    def __init__(self,neg,op,value,ad1): 
        self.ad1 = ad1
        self.internal_value = self.value  #Not yet initialized!!
        super(childA,self).__init__(neg,op,value)
```

this code can be put in the `preprocess()` or some other function that gets called *first* in `runme()`

```
def preprocess(self): 
    self.internal_value = value
    #Rest of the stuff
```

Comment: take a look at http://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/ ; I think it is no illogical at all to call `super()` at the end if `__init__` to delegate completion of class initialization.

Comment: Why do you think "that does not _appear_ to be right"? This is exactly what you need in that case and this is the simplest solution. I dont see any reason in using very _sophisticated_ code just because someone told you _easy_ solution does not appear to be right.

Comment: @running.t Yes you are right. Actually my original solution did not envisage removing `runme()` call from children. Have editted my question to include what I am doing now, because two people posted the same answer and then removed it

Answer (score 0):

If the children's `__init__` require partially initialized objects to proceed, calling `super()` at the end will not work indeed. If that's the case, you could call `runme` form `__new__` in `myBase`:

```
class myBase(object):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = super(myBase, cls).__new__(cls)
        obj.__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        obj.runme()

    def __init__(self, a):
        print 'myBase init'
        self.list = ['myBase', a]

    def runme(self):
        print 'myBase:', self.list

class ChildA(myBase):
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        print 'ChildA init'
        super(ChildA, self).__init__(a)
        self.list.extend(['ChildA', b])

    def runme(self):
        print 'ChildA:', self.list

class ChildAA(ChildA):
    def __init__(self, a, b, c):
        print 'ChildAA init'
        super(ChildAA, self).__init__(a, b)
        self.list.extend(['ChildAA', c])

    def runme(self):
        print 'ChildAA:', self.list
```

You can order the code inside the various `__init__` functions as required by the initialisation process, and the proper `runme` function will always be called after `__init__` completes:

```
>>> ChildA(1, 2)
ChildA init
myBase init
ChildA: ['myBase', 1, 'ChildA', 2]
>>> ChildAA(1, 2, 3)
ChildAA init
ChildA init
myBase init
ChildAA: ['myBase', 1, 'ChildA', 2, 'ChildAA', 3]
```